# Firestore security rules - Update array field - Allow only push (arrayUnion)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is it possible to allow only push in an array field (in a document), but block write to any existing value in this array ?

```
myDocument: {
    myArray: [
        "value1",
        "value2"
    ]
}
```

I would like to add `"value3"` in `myArray`. I am planning to use this method proposed in the [firestore documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)

But I want to block any other update to the `myArray` field except the above one and I didn't find a elegant way to do this with the cloud firestore security rules.

Is there a way to accept the update of the `myArray` field if it is being updated with `arrayUnion` and block all other update request ?

Comment: Take a look at the operations on list type objects.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List

Comment: Thanks !! I didn't knew this part of the documentation. It is super useful !! Thank you very much. I think I am going to be able to set up a good rule for what I want with the functions presented in this documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Because it's never too late!

Here is my solution! To permit only update of a field using arrayUnion, i use two things:

- `.size()` to check if the user is updating the array adding only one element, so i check if the size of the new array is equal to the size of the old array + 1

`request.resource.data.offers.size() == resource.data.offers.size() + 1`

- `.hasAll` to be sure that the user is only adding a new value without editing existing ones (really important point ⚠️)

`request.resource.data.offers.hasAll(resource.data.offers)`

And the final version where offers is my array who accept only `arrayUnion`  as update

```
match /swaps/{swapId} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow update: if (
          request.resource.data.offers.size() == resource.data.offers.size() + 1
          && request.resource.data.offers.hasAll(resource.data.offers)
      );
      allow delete: if false;
}
```

Comment: I like it, but you're not checking the ordering of the array...that's the last piece I need

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most comprehensive solution that ensures a few things:

- Only one item was added
- The item was added to the end of the array
- The existing array items have not been changed or re-arranged

  ```
  match /winners/{gameId} {

    // Not really important stuff:
    allow create: if false; // I'm creating documents with a cloud function, don't want users to create them with random data.
    allow delete: if false;
    allow read: if request.auth != null;

    // THE IMPORTANT STUFF:
    allow update: if 
      request.auth != null // Not really important to the question, but I always make sure users are authenticated.
      &&
      (
        request.resource.data.winners.size() == resource.data.winners.size() + 1 // Ensure only one item was added.
        && 
        resource.data.winners == request.resource.data.winners[0:resource.data.winners.size()] // This is the most important part - make sure the original array is contained in the first part of the new array. See notes below for more info how it works.
      );
  }
  ```

The key is to create a sublist from the new list & compare it to the original list (arrays are called lists in security rules). The sublist needs to be the same length as the original list, so we use the [range operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) `[i:j]` to create a sublist from the new list, starting at index `0` and having the same length as the original list. Note that the docs are currently wrong, saying that the range operator takes two indices. Based on my testing it really takes a start index & a number of elements to include.